# Inheritance for test setup

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-3.x, python-unittest

I currently have several TestCases that have the same setup / tearDown code. I thought the following setup to remove duplication.

clientsetup.py

```
class BaseClientTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        #Do setup    
    def tearDown(self):
        #Do tear down
```

test_myothertestcase.py

```
class MyOtherTestCase(BaseClientTestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        super(BaseClientTestCase, self).setUp()
        pass

    def tearDown(self):
        super(BaseClientTestCase, self).tearDown()
        pass
```

This allows me to remove duplication, and then be able to add some specific setup/teardown when required. Althought the problem I run into, 
is that my Testloader stopped working.

```
unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromName('tests.test_myothertestcase')
```

The error returned is the following:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'test_myothertestcase'
```

The test loader will take the name to look for from the command line, so it has to be a string. For some reason it no longer recognizes the `MyOtherTestCase` as if the inheritance doesn't work as I would expect it.

How can I make this work?

**Extended info**

Structure

```
app/
  ...
manage.py
tests/
    __init__.py
    test_myothertestcase.py
```

manage.py

```
@manager.command
def test(coverage=False,testcase=None):
    """Run the unit tests."""

    suite = None
    if testcase:
        suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromName("tests.%s" % testcase)
    else:
        suite = unittest.TestLoader().discover('tests')

    unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)
```

StackTrace:

```
  File "./manage.py", line 46, in <module>
    manager.run()
  File "/path/v_env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask_script/__init__.py", line 412, in run
    result = self.handle(sys.argv[0], sys.argv[1:])
  File "/path/v_env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask_script/__init__.py", line 383, in handle
    res = handle(*args, **config)
  File "/path/v_env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask_script/commands.py", line 216, in __call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "./manage.py", line 30, in test
    suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromName("tests.%s" % testcase)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/unittest/loader.py", line 114, in loadTestsFromName
    parent, obj = obj, getattr(obj, part)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'test_myothertestcase'
```

Comment: Is your capitalisation actually correct? Python is case sensitive and the example class you gave was `MyOtherTestCase` but the error you gave was `myothertestcase`...

Comment: @TomDalton I need to provide the name of the python file, that is why it is lower case.

Comment: Can you post your directory/file structure and the full stacktrace? Do you have a module named "tests"? Are both classes in the same file?

Comment: Done. Keep in mind, code stops working as soon as I change the class I extend in MyOtherTestCase to BaseClientTestCase

Comment: Unless there is a more verbose mode I think this is all.

Comment: What happens if you replace that line with two lines, `import tests.test_myothertestcase`, `suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromModule(tests.test_myothertestcase)`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75664/discussion-between-tom-dalton-and-giannis).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in chat, replacing

```
suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromName()
```

with

```
import importlib
test_module = importlib.import_module("tests.%s" % testcase)
suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromModule(test_module)
```

works. It seems like a bug in the loadTestsFromName, but maybe others know why it happens.

Comment: import importlib
        test_module = importlib.import_module("tests.%s" % testcase)
        suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromModule(test_module)